# Sifrei on Book of Devarim

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, midrash, chazal

Where can I find the Sifre on the book of Devarim online in text form (as opposed to Pdf)?

The commentary of the Netziv would also be appreciated.

Comment: Regarding the Netziv, which commentary? He wrote a [bunch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naftali_Zvi_Yehuda_Berlin#Bibliography).

Comment: @Bachrach44 I think he means the commentary on the Midrashei Halacha

Comment: I know the Netziv wrote a commentary on the mechilta, but I don't see a commentary on Sifre anywhere. @mevaqesh - any guidance? What are you looking for here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sifre (on Bamidbar and Devarim)
https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99

Netziv - assuming you mean HaEmek Davar (and not Davar HaEmek or one of the others), Sefaria has most of it:
http://www.sefaria.org/Haamek_Davar_on_Genesis
http://www.sefaria.org/Haamek_Davar_on_Exodus
http://www.sefaria.org/Haamek_Davar_on_Leviticus

Bamidbar will be coming in the next week or 2. No word on Devarim yet - we need to locate a good scan first. (Or a book we can scan).